What should i do if my expo can’t been install on android
I have just bundled my expo app and i got an .aab file then i converted it to .apks and finally i got .apk using apktool m , when i install this app on bluestack x emulator it works very well
But when i try to install it on physical android device it says “app not installed” or “can’t install this app” what should i do
I have just bundled my expo app and i got an .aab file then i converted it to .apks and finally i got .apk using apktool m , when i install this app on bluestack x emulator it works very well
But when i try to install it on physical android device it says “app not installed” or “can’t install this app” what should i do
I changed the pack name from
com.abueldahab.madinaty
To
com.madinaty.madinaty and i still get the same error i thought this will fix the problem
this is package.json
{
  "name": "list2024",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "~19.0.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.1.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.6.1",
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-root-siblings": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "3.29.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4"
  },
  "private": true
}


and this is app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "madinaty",
    "slug": "madinaty",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "scheme": "your-app-scheme",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#f06231"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#f06231"
      },
      "package": "com.madinaty.madinaty"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png",
      "bundler": "metro"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router"
    ],
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "7a8829bb-930f-4fc9-ada0-4f19c83d2be5"
      }
    }
  }
}



Instead of generating aab file, try generating apk with following cmd: eas build -p android --profile preview . I am assuming you are using expo managed workflow.
